# promise-ftp unknown command with ftp.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, host, node-ftp

I am using promise ftp to get a file and getting an error "**unknown command**".
Putting debug mode on gives me the following output.

```
[connection] > 'USER ecopo108'
[connection] < '331 User userrrrr OK. Password required\r\n'
[parser] < '331 User userrrrr  OK. Password required\r\n'
[parser] Response: code=331, buffer='User userrrrr OK. Password required'
[connection] > 'PASS password'
[connection] < '230 OK. Current restricted directory is /\r\n'
[parser] < '230 OK. Current restricted directory is /\r\n'
[parser] Response: code=230, buffer='OK. Current restricted directory is /'
[connection] > 'FEAT'
[connection] < '211-Extensions supported:\r\n EPRT\r\n IDLE\r\n MDTM\r\n SIZE\r\n MFMT\r\n REST STREAM\r\n MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;\r\n MLSD\r\n AUTH TLS\r\n PBSZ\r\n PROT\r\n UTF8\r\n TVFS\r\n ESTA\r\n PASV\r\n EPSV\r\n SPSV\r\n ESTP\r\n211 End.\r\n'
[parser] < '211-Extensions supported:\r\n EPRT\r\n IDLE\r\n MDTM\r\n SIZE\r\n MFMT\r\n REST STREAM\r\n MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;\r\n MLSD\r\n AUTH TLS\r\n PBSZ\r\n PROT\r\n UTF8\r\n TVFS\r\n ESTA\r\n PASV\r\n EPSV\r\n SPSV\r\n ESTP\r\n211 End.\r\n'
[parser] Response: code=211, buffer='Extensions supported:\r\n EPRT\r\n IDLE\r\n MDTM\r\n SIZE\r\n MFMT\r\n REST STREAM\r\n MLST type*;size*;sizd*;modify*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.uid*;UNIX.gid*;unique*;\r\n MLSD\r\n AUTH TLS\r\n PBSZ\r\n PROT\r\n UTF8\r\n TVFS\r\n ESTA\r\n PASV\r\n EPSV\r\n SPSV\r\n ESTP\r\nEnd.'
[connection] > 'OPTS UTF8 ON'
[connection] < '200 OK, UTF-8 enabled\r\n'
[parser] < '200 OK, UTF-8 enabled\r\n'
[parser] Response: code=200, buffer='OK, UTF-8 enabled'
[connection] > 'TYPE I'
[connection] < '200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary\r\n'
[parser] < '200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary\r\n'
[parser] Response: code=200, buffer='TYPE is now 8-bit binary'
[connection] > 'CWD ./public_html'
[connection] < '250 OK. Current directory is /public_html\r\n'
[parser] < '250 OK. Current directory is /public_html\r\n'
[parser] Response: code=250, buffer='OK. Current directory is /public_html'
[connection] > 'EPSV'
[connection] < '500 Unknown command\r\n'
[parser] < '500 Unknown command\r\n'
[parser] Response: code=500, buffer='Unknown command'
{ Error: Unknown command
    at makeError (C:\Users\Devon\Desktop\logfiles\node_modules\@icetee\ftp\lib\connection.js:1128:13)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Devon\Desktop\logfiles\node_modules\@icetee\ftp\lib\connection.js:122:25)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Parser._write (C:\Users\Devon\Desktop\logfiles\node_modules\@icetee\ftp\lib\parser.js:61:10)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:396:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:382:5)
    at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.ondata (C:\Users\Devon\Desktop\logfiles\node_modules\@icetee\ftp\lib\connection.js:298:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:601:20) code: 500 }
[connection] < '500 Logout.\r\n'
```

The following is my code to get the `robot.txt` file however it doesn't get into the .then block after the ftp.get I can pull it down with an ftp client like Filezilla using the same configuration (port,host,user and pass). I get the same result without the `ftp.cmd` and have tried multiple different paths

```
const PromiseFtp = require("promise-ftp");
const fs = require("fs");

const config = {
  host: "host",
  user: "user",
  password: "pass",
  debug: console.log
};
function testFtp() {
  var ftp = new PromiseFtp();
  ftp
    .connect(config)
    .then(() => {
      return ftp.cwd("./public_html");
    })
    .then(() => {
      return ftp.get("robots.txt");
    })
    .then(function(stream) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        stream.once("close", resolve);
        stream.once("error", reject);
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("robots.txt"));
      });
    })
    .then(function() {
      return ftp.end();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      ftp.end();
    });
}

testFtp();
```

using node.js & promise-ftp 1.3.5

Comment: Do you happen to be using IPv6?

Comment: The EPSV command instructs the server to got into "extended passive mode", which a quick search tells me is typically used for IPv6.

Comment: Could you please provide the full debug output, i.e. including the initial connect and the response to the FEAT command? It should also include if IPv4 or IPv6 is used for the connection. If IPv6 is used there is no way around EPSV. If IPv4 is used it might use EPSV if the server claims to support it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I updated the question with the error and log messages, also I looked up the server and it says it doesn't not support ipv6

Answer (score 0):

According to the response of the server to the `FEAT` command the server is claiming support for EPRT and EPSV extensions:

```
> FEAT
< 211-Extensions supported:
<  EPRT
<  ...
<  EPSV
<  ...
< 211 End
```

Based on this the FTP client is using these commands, but now the server is claiming that the command is not supported, contradicting its own statement earlier:

```
> EPSV
< 500 Unknown command
```

This means that either the server is broken or that there is some broken (transparent?) FTP proxy in the middle which does not support EPSV but fails to delete the claimed support from the servers original response to the FEAT command.

In any way - it is not the fault of the FTP client. The problem is not your code but on the server side.

Based on the code for [node-ftp](https://github.com/icetee/node-ftp/) which is used by promise-ftp there [must be a way to set an option](https://github.com/icetee/node-ftp/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L78) `forcePasv` to enforce the use of `PASV` even if the server claims to support `EPSV`. I'm not really familiar with all the code but I suggest you try something like this:

```
const config = {
  ...
  debug: console.log,
  forcePasv: true,
};
```